# Vagrant add to PATH

Tags: linux, bash, macos, vagrant

I've just installed [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) now I would like to make for example `vagrant up` global. In the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#connecting-via-ssh) I read this:

Sometimes you may want to vagrant up your Homestead machine from anywhere on your filesystem. You can do this on Mac / Linux systems by adding a Bash function to your Bash profile. On Windows, you may accomplish this by adding a "batch" file to your PATH. These scripts will allow you to run any Vagrant command from anywhere on your system and will automatically point that command to your Homestead installation:

**Mac / Linux**

```
function homestead() {
    ( cd ~/Homestead && vagrant $* )
}
```

But when I add the code above to my `~/.bash_profile`:

[image]

And restart the terminal `vagrant up` is not working globally. I have no experience with the `~/.bash_profile` file.

I would appreciate it if someone could put me in the right direction

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bash function allows you to type things like: `homestead up` and it will change directories to Homestead and pass the vagrant command in front of any other vagrant command.  homestead up means cd homestead, and vagrant up. Typing `vagrant up` doesn't invoke the function and vagrant isn't in your path.

What you're looking for is simply adding vagrant to your path.  You may do this by adding the executable path of vagrant.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/vagrant:
```

So, you're bash profile would read:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/:~/composer/vendor/bin:
```

Note: I'm guessing your vagrant is installed in /usr/local/bin; it might be installed elsewhere, in which case put the proper path in lieu of /usr/local/bin.